# How to enable and disable slide toggle in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have generated list of mat slide toggle's using for loop, but what want is, when I click on one slide toggle other slide toggles should be disabled.

my code:

HTML:

```
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mt-2" *ngFor="let data of attributes">
              <mat-slide-toggle>{{data}}</mat-slide-toggle>
        </div>
    </div>
```

TS:

```
   attributes = ["Last 7 days", "Last 30 days", "Last 60 days"]
```

In this scenario, when I click on "Last 7 days" slide toggle, then "Last 30 days", "Last 60 days" should be disabled,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change your `attributes` array to hold objects with the attribute and a property for the disabled state. E.g. `options = [{id: 1, title: "Last 7 days", disabled: false}, ...];` Add an `id` to identify which one was toggled.
2. Bind the `disabled` property to the `disabled`  input and the `id` to the `id` attribute.
3. See the [API Docs](https://material.angular.io/components/slide-toggle/api) and use `@Output() change: EventEmitter<MatSlideToggleChange>` event to call a function which iterates over your array and set all disabled flags to `true` except the one which triggered the event.
4. Do the same thing for enabling all toggles.

```
  <div *ngFor="let data of options">
    <mat-slide-toggle 
       [id]="data.id" 
       [disabled]="data.disabled" 
       (change)="disableAll($event)">
        {{data.title}}
    </mat-slide-toggle>
  </div>
```

```
  options = [
    { id: 1, title: "Last 7 days", disabled: false },
    { id: 2, title: "Last 30 days", disabled: false },
    { id: 3, title: "Last 60 days", disabled: false }
  ];

  disableAll(ev: MatSlideToggleChange) {
    if (ev.checked) {
      this.options
        .filter(opt => opt.id != ev.source._elementRef.nativeElement.id)
        .forEach(opt => (opt.disabled = true));
    } else {
      this.options.forEach(opt => (opt.disabled = false));
    }
  }
```

Here's a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhmsyp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fslide-toggle-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 1):

```
 <mat-slide-toggle color="primary"
        place
        [(ngModel)]="disalbeShipping"></mat-slide-toggle>
    <mat-form-field appearance='outline'
        validationMessageContainer>
        <mat-label>Tax Shipping Rate</mat-label>
        <input matInput
            placeholder=''
            formControlName=''
            required
            [disabled]="disalbeShipping">
    </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).