# How to disable a element using attribute directive?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I created a custom directive to disable an element given a condition but it's not work as I expected. I tried

```
this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "disabled", "true");
```

and

```
this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled = true;
```

But none of them worked.

I tested this directive on mat-slide-toggle. If I add `disabled` attribute direct on HTML as below it works.

```
 <mat-slide-toggle
          [(ngModel)]="element.habilitado"
          (change)="toggleActive(element)"
          myCustomDirective
          disabled
        >
```

Here's my directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2 } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[myCustomDirective]",
})
export class MyCustomDirective implements OnInit {

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {
    console.log("nova diretiva");
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.elementRef.nativeElement);
    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.elementRef.nativeElement, "disabled", "true");
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.disabled = true;
  }

 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your question is duplicated, it has already been asked and answered here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63411260/4017037

Comment: It doesn't work because this variable doesn't exist in the component

Comment: yep, if this is a duplicate, it's not a duplicate of the question/answer @LeandroSouza referenced

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS selector `[ng-reflect-disabled]` to trigger the disabled value.

and add `[disabled]="true"` in your HTML file.

and in your CSS file add the below code:

```
mat-slide-toggle[ng-reflect-disabled='true'] {
  cursor: default;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```